# WampServer: Warning: mail(): SMTP server response: 530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first

Tags: php, email

I am having an issue with WampServer, I tried creating a contact form but it isn't working. BIOS stopped recognizing my 2GB RAM chip so my system thinks it's 32-bit instead of 64-bit. Here's the PHP error table:

```
( ! ) Warning: mail(): SMTP server response: 530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first. 8sm9902426ioe.8 - gsmtp in C:\Users\miner\Desktop\Configuration Creator\www\contact\mail.php on line 10
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0004  245672  {main}( )   ..\mail.php:0
2   0.0004  246648  mail ( )    ..\mail.php:10
```

Here's my code:

contact.html

```
<form action="mail.php" method="POST">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" placeholder="Name">
    <div class="padded-bottom"></div>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="Email">
    <div class="padded-bottom"></div>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="subject" placeholder="Subject">
    <div class="padded-bottom"></div>
    <textarea type="text" class="form-control no-resize paragraph" rows="8" name="message" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
    <div class="padded-bottom"></div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button> <button type="reset" class="btn btn-default">Clear Form</button>
</form>
```

mail.php

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$subject = $_POST['subject'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$from = 'From: '. $name; 
$to = 'email@example.com'; 
$subject = $subject;
$body = "From: $name\n Email: $email\n Message:\n $message";     
if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)) { 
    echo '<p>Your message has been sent!</p>';
} else { 
    echo '<p>Something went wrong. Please manually <a href="mailto:email@example.com">email me</a> and include a screenshot/copy of the log above.</p>'; 
}
?>
```

and finally, php.ini

```
[mail function]
; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/smtp
SMTP = smtp.gmail.com
; http://php.net/smtp-port
smtp_port = 587

; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/sendmail-from
sendmail_from = email@example.com
```

Sorry if it's a duplicate, my problem is different than others.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change this

```
; http://php.net/smtp
SMTP = smtp.gmail.com
; http://php.net/smtp-port
smtp_port = 587
```

to this (variant #1):

```
; http://php.net/smtp
SMTP = ssl://smtp.gmail.com
; http://php.net/smtp-port
smtp_port = 465
```

or to this (variant #2):

```
; http://php.net/smtp
SMTP = tls://smtp.gmail.com
; http://php.net/smtp-port
smtp_port = 587
```

One of my variants should be OK for you.

But I don't recommend use mail() function all the more so with Wamp (sockets will be good solution).

**UPDATE**

Do you really use Gmail smtp-service with mail() or you post Gmail only for example? For using Gmail smtp-service you need authentication (password+username), but mail() function don't support it. You need write personal mail-function based on sockets or use ready-made solutions like hMailServer and send mail using this software (hMailServer creditnails should be write to php.ini).

Comment: (!) Don't forget restart your Wamp after changes in php.ini

Comment: I got it working a while ago with the same thing just different system architecture. http://stackoverflow.com/users/5757238/vika-marquez I can't find your username so I got to link your profile.

Comment: Because mail() don't support authorisation (username + password). See my update again, I already wrote what you need do. Or you need write personal mail-function based on sockets, or you need use software like hMailServer (creditnails for hMailServer should be add to php.ini)